# Uncaught Type Error: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined... but it's defined?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm going over stuff to drill it in, I started a small and easy project and I'm trying to get images to switch once a button is pressed, I've defined everything I need to with variables but when I click the button it just gives me the error: Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'src' of undefined, even though what I'm asking it to set the src property to, IS defined and I dont' understand why it's having trouble, I can't see a problem or reason for this?

I've tried re identifying the HTML elements and tried using different elements is Js to see if there's a problem I missed, I tried re-writing the code to eliminate anything I couldn't see. I've run through the rest of my code to check for any other bugs that could be messing with the execution.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="coin">
    <img src="images/coin-0.jpg" alt="Coin" id="coin-img" />
    <button id="coin-flip">Flip Coin</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#coin-flip').addEventListener('click', function() 
{
    var flip = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    document.querySelector('#coin-img').document.src = 'images/coin-' + 
    flip + '.jpg';
});
```

Based on the Math.random working, I expected it's variable to change the img src when executed. Everything has been working up until this point.

Comment: not `.document.src`, just `.src`

Answer (score 0):

**Whats wrong?**

It gives you the undefined error because the 2nd "document" you wrote in the line below is not defined.

```
    document.querySelector('#coin-img').document.src = 'images/coin-' +
```

**Solution**

I suspect you wrote that 2nd "document" by error and just wish to **change the "src" property straight at the "querySelector", instead of on the 2nd "document"**.

This should work as "querySelector" returns the HTML element you ask for, in this case an "img" element. Which has the src property.

```
document.querySelector('#coin-flip').addEventListener('click', function() 
{
    var flip = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    document.querySelector('#coin-img').src = 'images/coin-' + 
    flip + '.jpg';
});
```

Provided that everything else is set up correct, then this solution should work.